# Replace string between two patterns with sed - no error, no result

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Example from the file where I want to change the username:

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
<username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
```

[Here is my regex test](https://regex101.com/r/MyqtaQ/1) to ensure it matches.

And finally the sed command that completes without error and does not change anything:

```
sed -i -e 's/(<username><!\[CDATA\[).*(\]\]><\/username>)/TEST/g' path/to/file.xml
```

This should be the result:

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
TEST
```

---

Besides it not replacing at all, I need it to work like this in order to keep the capturing groups before and after, effectively only replacing the username:

```
sed -i -e 's/(<username><!\[CDATA\[).*(\]\]><\/username>)/\1TEST\2/g' path/to/file.xml
```

But that returns this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 57: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

So I think the capturing groups are matched to loosely somehow since it doesn't really capture them, which makes the replace not replace anything in the first place?

The end result I want is this:

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
<username><![CDATA[TEST]]></username>
```

Comment: Why are you using a regexp to parse XML?  Anyway, you don't have any capture groups - you need to use `\(..\)` or (in GNU sed) add the `-r` option to use Extended Regular Expression syntax.

Comment: Not necessarily parsing XML, just replacing text between two patterns. The advice in your comment is the way I got it to work, so thank you. It I simply didn't know about the extended regexp. This is how my SED looks now in my loop: `sed -i -r -e 's/(<'"$key"'><!\[CDATA\[).*(\]\]><\/'"$key"'>)/\1'"${db_local[$key]}"'\2/g' ${path_local[site]}/path/to/file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

A possible awk solution that could be much more refined:

```
 awk '{if ($0 ~ /username/) gsub(/CDATA\[.+\]/, "CDATA[TEST]"); print $0 }' file.txt
```

In words:

If the line contains username, then sub out all instances of CDATA[] with CDATA[TEST]. This will change the line. Then print the each line. The regex could be refined more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/root/,"TEST")}1' file

<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
<username><![CDATA[TEST]]></username>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to provide some explanation of your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any capture groups - you need to use `(..)` or (in GNU sed) add the `-r` option to use Extended Regular Expression syntax.
                    – Toby Speight

It I simply didn't know about the extended regexp. This is how my SED looks now in my loop:
`sed -i -r -e 's/(<'"$key"'><![CDATA[).*(]]><\/'"$key"'>)/\1'"${db_local[$key]}"'\2/g' ${path_local[site]}/path/to/file.xml`
                    – a_rts